# set_xticklables() generates correct plot in DataFrame.plot but throws typeError in matplotlib for len()

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

Okay, so I have looked for the answer to my question, but cannot seem to find it. I am trying to make a bar chart with text labels using pandas and `xticks` on Python 2.7. this is the code I have. Here is the issue...it works as intended but throws an error:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(25,9)) #creates figure object
fig.suptitle('Your Team\'s Check-in Performance', fontsize=20,fontweight='bold') #adds title layer


ax = fig.add_subplot(111) #add new subplot to figure
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85) #move down for subtitle
ax.set_title('Check-ins by Mentor') #add subtitle
ax.set_ylabel('Check-ins') #y label
ax.set_xlim(-1,38)
ax.grid()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,37,1))
ax.set_xticklabels(mentor_checkin_ranks['Name'],rotation='vertical', fontsize=14,visible=True)
mentor_checkin_ranks.plot.bar(ax=ax,color='slategrey',xticks=ax.get_xticks)
```

Here is the error, it has to do with the interaction between 'matplotlib' and `DataFrame.plot()` sets the `xticks` on the axis:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in set_ticks(self, ticks, minor)
   1595         # XXX if the user changes units, the information will be lost here
   1596         ticks = self.convert_units(ticks)
-> 1597         if len(ticks) > 1:
   1598             xleft, xright = self.get_view_interval()
   1599             if xright > xleft:

TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()
```

Any insight would be helpful, thanks a bunch , guys.

Update: changing `xticks=ax.get_xticks` to `xticks=ax.get_xticks()` fixes the error but removes the text labels. Changing to `xticks=ax.get_xticklabels()` works as intended but throws another error because the xticks are not floats.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question, it was because pandas overwrote the `ax.set_xticklabels()` when I called `Dataframe.plot.bar()`. All I had to do was move it to the bottom and `plt.show()` afterward like this:

```
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,37,1))
mentor_checkin_ranks.plot.bar(ax=ax,color='slategrey',xticks=ax.get_xticks())
ax.set_xticklabels(mentor_checkin_ranks['Name'].values,rotation='vertical', fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

And boom, it works and throws no errors.